# One expression to support different format strings

Tags: regex

**Sample Format**

```
-q12345(x666)-55_data.jpg
```

I tried with `([\w/-]+)\.jpg` and it returns only `-55_data.jpg`. Actually, I need to get the whole value that is `-q12345(x666)-55_data.jpg`.

Also, I need the **same expression** to support **following formats**. Is that possible. Thanks.

```
123-55-FULLY_DAT.jpg

456-67-TABLE-OPEN_SMA.jpg

12431-56-78-Q789-RA-R-Z_DETAIL.jpg

E811-33-25(7)-98Z(5)-44-79-34_LARGE.jpg

UTE_B70000-94-65-15-56-25-06-46-16_HEAVY.jpg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the forward slash and add `()` inside the character class,

```
([\w()-]+)\.jpg
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/qC9cH4/5)

Answer (score 1):

```
((?:-?[\w)()]+-)*[\w]+\.jpg)
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/qC9cH4/6